# Regex for a phone number where a phone number exclusively contains numbers in the range of 5 to 15 digits

Tags: php, regex

My regex:`/[0-9]{5,15}/` that satisfies a number e.g. `8801778620485` which is fine.
But it also satisfies a number i.e `8801778620485|123456|987123456` (Three parts are a single phone number). I don't want this kind of phone number to be accepted. I want exclusively numbers without any special characters like (`|, ?, *, -`) these no special characters are allowed, only numbers are allowed.

Comment: Javascript, python or php?

Comment: This is for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number.match(/^\d{5,15}$/);`

This should work `\d` for `[0-9]`, and start and end of the expression specified so that a a string like `123456|12345678` doesn't result in a partial match.